# Python, making 3 list with dates

Tags: python, python-2.7, csv

I need some help making some list out of a CSV file:

Right now, I imported a file and made two lists. My code is here:

The list `week`, contain all weeks, date taken from `row[0]`.

The list `weight = []` contains all weights, from `row[1]`.

My code you see here so far:

```
import csv
import datetime
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from pprint import pprint

#Open Data/File
data1 = open('wloss.csv', 'r')
reader1 = csv.reader(data1, delimiter=',')

week = []
weight = []
dateTime = []

week_year_2011 = []
week_year_2012 = []
week_year_2013 = []
weight_year_2011 = []
weight_year_2012 = []
weight_year_2013 = []

for row in reader1:

    if row[0] != 'week':
        week.append(row[0][:-13])
    if row[1] != 'weight loss':
        weight.append(row[1])

for item in week:
    dateTime.append(datetime.datetime.strptime(item, '%Y-%m-%d'))
```

The week list i got dates from 2004 too 2014

like this (you only see data from 2005):

```
datetime.datetime(2005, 4, 10, 0, 0),
datetime.datetime(2005, 4, 17, 0, 0),
datetime.datetime(2005, 4, 24, 0, 0),
datetime.datetime(2005, 5, 1, 0, 0),
datetime.datetime(2005, 5, 8, 0, 0),
datetime.datetime(2005, 5, 15, 0, 0),
datetime.datetime(2005, 5, 22, 0, 0),
```

i know the first date and last date from 2011 is:

```
datetime.datetime(2011, 1, 2, 0, 0),
datetime.datetime(2011, 12, 25, 0, 0),
```

How do I put in `datetime` data from only 2011, 2012 and 2013 in 3 new lists like I already defined under here:

```
week_year_2011 = []
week_year_2012 = []
week_year_2013 = []
```

Should make a `for` statement or something??

Also how do I get the right weight from 2011, 2012, 2013 and put them in 3 other lists like this:

```
weight_year_2011 = []
weight_year_2012 = []
weight_year_2013 = []
```

I have to make a 3 plots (in 1 graph) with data for 2011, 2012 and 2013.
Hope someone could help on how to make these new lists and put the right data in it.

Answer (score 2):

I'd use a *dictionary* to group the data by date.

You appear to have a CSV file with a header on the first row. Here is a simpler version that splits out data into separate lists by date:

```
import csv
import datetime

by_year = {}

with open('wloss.csv', 'rb') as data1:
    reader = csv.reader(data1)
    next(reader, None)  # skip first row with headers

    for week, weight_loss in reader:
        date = datetime.datetime.strptime(week, '%Y-%m-%d').date()
        by_year.setdefault(date.year, []).append((week, weight_loss))
```

This builds a dictionary keyed on year, each value a list of `(date, weight_loss)` tuples.

Comment: I would also suggest a dict.  You could use `defaultdict(list)` to avoid the need for setdefault, of course.

Comment: @JohnZwinck: Yup, but I wanted to keep it a little simpler since I was radically rewriting the whole code here already.. Best not to introduce too many new concepts in one.

Comment: Well, if i try the code you wrote... i get I/O operation on closed file error.

Comment: @user3371053: You didn't use my indentation then; the `with` statement will close the file automatically when the block (determined by indentation) is done.

Comment: Well, i just don't get it :(

Comment: I'm sorry to hear that. I did notice there was a small syntax error in my answer (missing `:` at the end of the `with` statement) that may have thrown you.

Comment: Could u not just make something like this:

    for row in week:
        if week <= '2011':
            year_2011.append(week)
    print year_2011